# Реализация Retrofit запросов

Tags: android, архитектура, retrofit

Возникли вопросы в специфике реализации Retrofit запросов. Информации о самих запросах и их выполнении огромное количество, но почему то мало кто задается вопросам следующего содержания:

1. Стоит ли помещать запросы в сервис, что он был доступен после выключения приложения? Вдруг пользователь включит приложение и сразу выключит?
2. Стоит ли делать запрос в сервисе (или как то иначе), чтобы он был доступен одновременно во всех активити? Вдруг запрос происходит в одной активити, а пользователь быстро переключился в новую, потом опять вернулся в старую. Запросы постоянно будут уходить и отменяться в OnDestroy, и в случае получения одним запросом всей базы, view так и не получат актуальную информацию с сервера.

Особенно вопросы относятся к post запросам, которые к примеру отправляются в одной активити и должны быть выполнены в любом случае, а пользователь в то время может свободно гулять по приложению

На всех информационных ресурсах разобраны мелочи выполнения запросов, а с идеологической точки зрения не ясно, как использовать так, чтобы избавиться от страха не получить или не отправить данные в случае неадекватного поведения пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос хороший, но есть нюанс. Дело в том, что этот момент остается на усмотрение разработчика, ибо только вы знаете, как необходимо делать запрос и дожидаться его.

1.Возможно, но сразу вспомните, что есть разные виды сервиса с разной стратегий и все они будут отличаться. Например Bound (bind) сервис ничем может не отличаться от того который вы описали с Lifecycle активити и отменяться. Если вы хотите добиться непрерывной работы то возможно подойдет foreground service, но со стороны безопасности будут вопросы, что вы делаете POST запросом.

2.Сама идеология Retrofit так заточена, чаще всего его выносят как HTTP module, который крутиться в Application слое, поэтому да, так делают и даже мб не один  клиент в этом модуле. Также создают очередь команд CommandQueue, часто используемый паттерн в этом месте, чтоб добиться последовательности/отмены/продолжения/сохранения/управления командами клиента.

Что качается View скорей всего, вам нужно правильно построить логику обновления сей в зависимости от изменения данных. Если структура верна, то в теории все ситуации когда View не отображает актуальные данные уйдут.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, мне близок второй озвученный Вами вариант. В моем случае, при использовании паттерна mvp, можно его частично скрестить с паттерном repository и получать его через application

Comment: @Foxek абсолютно верно, repository это мапер который может забрать логику кеширования запроса (cookie)  и также если система захочет освободить память вы тамже можете организовать логику сохранения/шифрования данных на др storage

Comment: Спасибо за совет